# C# Count down timer that continues after application restart

Tags: c#, timer

I need a timer that counts down from 1 hour and if the application gets restarted, it will continue to countdown where it was, so it doesnt start all over again? Help!! C#

Comment: No, If you restart a programme everything gets reset as it is well.... restarting...

Comment: I wonder how computers would survive if programs were allowed to keep their memory alive even after a reset... How many TBs of RAM would we need...?

Comment: You need to store it somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Add appsetting parameter that will keep value of the timer every N second. When you start (or restart) application check stored value of the timer and update remaining period accordingly. 
You can do this either with threads or with another timer that will be fired every N seconds. On second timer event write down remaining period and restart second timer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the countdown on a file that updates every second. And when the computer loads up, the program will read the file and continue the countdown.